# BoxWhiskerChart Notched: how is the notch calculated?

Tags: plotting, charts, implementation-details

I am aware of one convention for the uncertainty in a median:
it is 1.58 * IQR / Sqrt[n], where IQR is the inter-quartile range and n is the number of data points. This was proposed by McGill, Tukey, and Larsen in 1978, and is used by R for their boxplots.  It corresponds roughly to a 95% confidence interval.

It seems that the "Notched" function in Mathematica's BoxWhiskerChart function is using a different calculation, but I have failed to find any information on what that calculation is.

Comment: I believe the documentation says the fat part of the plot is bounded by the 1st and 3rd quartiles (Properties & Relations section). Am I missing something?

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries Those are the boundaries of the *box itself*. I think the OP is referring to the limits of the *notched part of the box*, when you request the `"Notched"` option.

Answer (score 7):

**Update:** You can control the median confidence interval using the suboption `"MedianConfidenceIntervalParameter"` of the option `Method`:

```
data = Table[RandomReal[BetaDistribution[a, 1.5], 100], {a, 1, 5, 1}]; 

opts = {{"Notched", {"MedianMarker", Purple}, {"MedianNotch", Orange}}, 
       ImageSize -> 300,  ChartElementFunction -> "GlassBoxWhisker"};
bwc1 = BoxWhiskerChart[data[[1]], ## & @@ opts, PlotLabel -> Style["Default" , 16]];
bwcs = BoxWhiskerChart[data[[1]], Sequence @@ opts,
     PlotLabel -> Style["MedianConfidenceIntervalParameter ->" <> ToString@#, 16],
     Method -> {"MedianConfidenceIntervalParameter" -> #}] & /@ 
     {1.7, .5, 1., 2., 3};

Row[{bwc1, bwcs[[1]]}]
```

[image]

```
Row[Rest@bwcs]
```

[image]

Note: The function `` Charting`iBoxWhiskerChart `` is the first function called in the `TracePrint` of `BoxWhiskerChart[...]`. One of its options is `"MedianConfidenceIntervalParameter"` with default value `1.7`:

```
Options[Charting`iBoxWhiskerChart, "MedianConfidenceIntervalParameter"]
```

> {"MedianConfidenceIntervalParameter" -> 1.7`}

---

**Original post:**

The core function used rendering the box plots in `BoxWhiskerChart` is `` System`BarFunctionDump`boxplot ``. You can see the code using

```
?? System`BarFunctionDump`boxplot
```

The relevant line that determines the median interval is

```
System`BarFunctionDump`medianInterval = 
 (System`BarFunctionDump`medianConfIntPara 1.25` System`BarFunctionDump`iqr)/
 ( 1.35` Sqrt[Length[System`BarFunctionDump`data]])
```

where `` System`BarFunctionDump`iqr `` is the `IQR` and the default value for the parameter `` System`BarFunctionDump`medianConfIntPara `` is previously defined as

```
System`BarFunctionDump`medianConfIntPara = 1.7`
```

So, the default value of the median interval parameter is

```
(1.7 1.25/1.35) IQR / Sqrt[n] = 1.574074 IQR / Sqrt[n]
```

The value of  `` System`BarFunctionDump`medianConfIntPara `` is controlled by the option  `"MedianConfIntPara"`  but I could not figure out how this option is to be used in `BoxWhiskerChart`.

Comment: This is brilliant (+1)! Would you mind sharing how you found out where to look for `boxplot` etc? I tried to dig around a bit, but came up empty.

Comment: @MarcoB, thank you for the vote and kind words. I use the general spelunking method: use ``?? *`*BoxWhisker*`` and click on some the results; found  that ``System`BarFunctionDump`boxplot`` is called by few functions that inspected. I was lucky to bump into something that was relevant without going through a long chain of other function calls.

Comment: Thank you! I will use this example as a study tool in spelunking, by trying to retrace your steps. I am curious to see how far I can get with this approach on my own, knowing a) that there is something to find; 2) what that something is already ;-)